# Importing ECEF WGS84 into ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, kml, arcgis-10.5, ecef

I have a file in ECEF WGS84 in meters.

I want to import these points in ArcMap 10.5 as point layer.

The file to import is in Excel format. 
I can import them with Excel to layer tool. I can see all the points, but I can't get them on the map in the right position.

Here is the file header and first line:

```
file_name,file_type,sequence_id,timestamp,GPS_time(s),ecef(x‌​),ecef(y),ecef(z),at‌​titude(x)=roll,attit‌​ude(y)=pitch,attitud‌​e(z)=pan,frame_id 
F:/DG_Paderborn-Borchen - Etteln_170620_Run1/2017-06-20_10-35-25/ladybug_panoramic_000‌​000.jpg,JPG,0,285833‌​39722,1181983021.108‌​2721,3922148.9627709‌​221,604199.614461860‌​27,4976781.334698205‌​8,-177.5736892226599‌​7,7.1055832760669553‌​,-79.315623440207304‌​,1068
```

Does somebody know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: How far from "in the right position" are your points?  What were the detailed steps that you performed to import them?

Comment: Its so far out of the world that it's lost. It is by the way a mistake from me, it should be CSV in my text, so Excel to layer.

Comment: file_name,file_type,sequence_id,timestamp,GPS_time(s),ecef(x),ecef(y),ecef(z),attitude(x)=roll,attitude(y)=pitch,attitude(z)=pan,frame_id
F:/DG_Paderborn-Borchen - Etteln_170620_Run1/2017-06-20_10-35-25/ladybug_panoramic_000000.jpg,JPG,0,28583339722,1181983021.1082721,3922148.9627709221,604199.61446186027,4976781.3346982058,-177.57368922265997,7.1055832760669553,-79.315623440207304,1068

Comment: Please [edit] your question to revise it with any requested information.

Comment: this is the header with one row with data, i am interested in mapping the ECEF(x) and ECEF(y) to a fitting EPSG code, or in some way getting it in. It should be in Germany, in the area Paderborn-Borchen area

Comment: ArcGIS doesn't support ECEF coordinates. You'll have to convert to lat-lon-h first.

Comment: I am converting nothing for now. Just import Excel (csv) to layer, and setting the excef (x) and ecef (y) to a fitting EPSG code. Ans I cant find any whom is getting it right. Do i need to convert them?

Comment: hi mkennedy, ok so i need to take the ECEF from dd:mm:ss into lat lon. Do you have a EPSG whom fits for this, like does 4326 works on this